# "Quest of providing" vs. "quest for providing"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, collocation, of-for

Which sentence is correct and why?

> 1. In our quest *of* providing unparalleled value to our customers.
> 2. In our quest *for* providing unparalleled value to our customers.

I understand that the preposition *of* indicates "related to or belonging to", whereas the preposition *for* indicates the use of something.

Answer (score 1):

Neither suggestion would sound natural in conventional English.  More conventional usage would be:

> In our quest **to provide** unparalleled value to our customers...

Even then, ‘quest’ feels artificial.  I can imagine going on a quest *for* something, or *to locate* something (i.e. I go questing/exploring), but not exactly to *provide* or *deliver* something.  More effective might be:

> **As part of our mission to provide** unparalleled value to our customers...